# In Nvidia Prime profiles, Intel selection is grayed out

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-prime

This is the output of the `sudo lshw -C display` command:

```
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:139 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4000000-a407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Output of `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version`

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  515.48.07  Fri May 27 03:26:43 UTC 2022
GCC version:  gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
```

[image: Screen of my nvidia-settings:]

Comment: This may help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1437154/1643791