# Intel-Only GPU Setting Grayed Out in NVIDIA Settings

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

```
sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:610-60f irq:185 memory:be000000-beffffff memory:6000000000-60ffffffff memory:6100000000-6101ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1200
       resources: iomemory:610-60f iomemory:400-3ff irq:186 memory:6188000000-6188ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

I am running NVIDIA driver `515.65.01` and Kubuntu `22.10`. I want to set my computer to only use my integrated GPU, as on-demand mode is still allowing Xorg to run on it. However, the setting to do so is grayed out. How can I fix this, or, failing that, accomplish this through some other method?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This only works on Ubuntu and Ubuntu flavors*

Intel-only mode can be manually enabled via `sudo prime-select intel` and then performing a system reboot. Intel-only mode remains grayed out but is selected.

[image]

I am pretty sure it does work as `nvidia-smi` returns the following message:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Comment: Before doing anything with `prime-select` make sure to have a backup. I mean a backup atleast like `timeshift`. I tried something similar once, and somehow it broke my DE. I couldnt even fix it.

Comment: The reason the option is greyed out is because optimus drives the HDMI port(s). If you disable the GPU, external monitors can be used.